# Bigtable 'write-requests' is not consistent

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I am writing data into BigTable from google storage using dataflow job, I am using 3 nodes BigTable cluster and has 25 workers working in parallel in my dataflow job

When I check the 'Write-requests' graph of the Big table then what I observe it fluctuates between 1.5k-9k, as per me it should remain consistent as I am consistently passing the data.

When I checked the logs I found this statement coming too often `'Retrying failed call. Failure #1, got: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Temporary problem while looking up metadata for table AID_KRUXID, cause=null}'`

Just want to understand why I am seeing such variations in 'Write-requests' does above logger statement has any impact on the write-request or there are other reasons which I am not aware of?

Thanks! in Advance

Comment: 1) Do you have a Dataflow job id that exhibits this problem? 2) Is anything else writing to this table, apart from your Dataflow job?

Comment: @jkff Only my job is writing to Big Table and the Job Id is 2016-09-13_07_47_13-11809669185152159324

Comment: Consider using 9 Dataflow workers, or increasing your Bigtable cluster to 8-9 nodes for the duration of the job.  25 workers will overwhelm 3 Bigtable cluster, leading to a bad state where high latency causes retries which further overwhelm Bigtable.  My rule of thumb is 3 client-side CPUs to 1 Bigtable node.

Comment: 3 cluster Big Table node should give us 30,000 QPS but when I check the 'write-requests' graph it varies between 1.5k-9k  since I am using 25 workers (I also tried with 50 workers) but my write-requests never exceeds 9k/sec. what we are trying is to reach at least 15k write-requests and then check how much time our job is taking based on that we can decide whether we want to increase nodes or not.                                                                                                       Could you please tell us why our write-requests is not exceeding 9k in 3 nodes big table cluster.

Comment: @Amandeep – are you writing into a brand-new, empty table?

Comment: 30,000 QPS is a bit misleading.  If you're doing writes, the 1.5k - 9k QPS is bulk writes.  There could be 100s of mutations in a single RPC.

Comment: @Misha Brukman yes I am writing to an empty table

Comment: @Amandeep – see my answer below for what you need to do since you're writing into a brand new table. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using 9 Dataflow workers, or increasing your Bigtable cluster to 8-9 nodes for the duration of the job. 25 workers will overwhelm 3 Bigtable cluster, leading to a bad state where high latency causes retries which further overwhelm Bigtable. My rule of thumb is 3 client-side CPUs to 1 Bigtable node.

You've asked this question a few times already on SO, and I've answered.  I'm sorry if my answer isn't clear.  The right balance of Dataflow workers and Cloud Bigtable nodes is the only way to fix this problem.

Comment: does that mean if I add more workers it will overwhelm the big table resulting in lots of retries? Now I am retrying the same job with 9 workers as suggested by you but still in logs I am seeing this entry 'Retrying failed call. Failure #1, got: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=null, cause=com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.StreamBufferingEncoder$Http2ChannelClosedException: Connection closed}'

Comment: huh.  Which class are you using?  And which jar version?

Comment: I am using 0.9.1 version of bigTable, 1.1.5 version of hbase and for io.netty I am using following dependency <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.33.Fork19</version>

Comment: Are you using CloudBigtableIO, BigtableIO or AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn?

Comment: We are using CloudBigtableIO, following is the piece of code which writes into BigTable:                                     CloudBigtableIO.initializeForWrite(p);
  PCollection<String> fileData  = p.apply("Reading Krux data from GS", TextIO.Read.from(options.getInputGSPath()));
  
  fileData.apply("Format as BT Mutation for AID" , ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Mutation>() {
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        convertFileDataToRow(c);
      }
      })).apply("Write to AID_KRUXID Table",CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(config));

Comment: one more thing I am seeing following log entry in my data flow job  'No operations completed within the last 30 seconds. There are still 2 rpcs and 2 retries in progress.' and it keeps on coming at the end after my job has reduced the number of workers and during this period nothing is written to BigTable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  We made some changes in 0.9.2 which may possibly fix this.  I'd need to dig into the logs for a full diagnosis.  That level of effort usually requires interaction through the Cloud Support team, which if I understand the support process (https://cloud.google.com/support/) requires the Gold support package.  Do you know if you have that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123456/discussion-between-solomon-duskis-and-amandeep).

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, the OP is writing into an empty table.

To improve the performance of writing into an empty table, you need to pre-split the table. If you don't pre-split the table, the table has a single tablet, which is hosted by a single Cloud Bigtable server node, so your throughput is limited to a single node, rather than parallelized across the entire cluster.

By pre-splitting the table, you are telling Cloud Bigtable to create a number of (empty) tablets, which will be distributed across the different server nodes.

You can pre-split the table only at creation time; after you've created the table, Bigtable takes over the management of tablet splits and merges, and you won't be able to influence it.

The other thing to note is that leaving a pre-split table idle for a while (more than a day, for example) will cause Bigtable to undo your splits, since there's no activity on the table. Thus, you should intend to start using a pre-split table soon after creation, before your work is undone.

The other rule of thumb is to aim for creating tablet splits such that each tablet will have ~512MB of data.

There are two ways you can tell Bigtable to pre-split the table:

1. [Using the HBase shell](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/managing-tables#splits)
2. Using any of these admin APIs:

   - [`Admin.createTable(HTableDescriptor desc, byte[][] splitKeys)`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#createTable-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor-byte:A:A-)

     Specify the split keys manually by computing them yourself. Useful if your data is not evenly distributed across the lexicographic keyspace.
   - [`Admin.createTable(HTableDescriptor desc, byte[] startKey, byte[] endKey, int numRegions)`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#createTable-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor-byte:A-byte:A-int-)

     Ask Bigtable to create `numRegions` number of even splits between the two provided keys: `startKey` and `endKey`. Note that what Bigtable calls *tablets*, HBase calls *regions* so these terms are equivalent.
   - [`Admin.createTableAsync(HTableDescriptor desc, byte[][] splitKeys)`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#createTableAsync-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor-byte:A:A-)

     Same as the first method, but async.